# Dynamically create JTextAreas?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Working on a GUI in Eclipse using WindowBuilder and ran into a roadblock..

I've created a JWindow with a drop-down box intended to display a list of people from a people array. The structure of my classes are:

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    int age;
    ArrayList<Goal> goals;
}

public class Goal {
    String name;
    int daysToComplete;
}
```

Within this JWindow GUI, the drop-down box lists out all of the Person instances. Once I select a person (let's say Bob) - I want to dynamically create labels and JTextAreas to list out Bob's attribute values, for example:

```
Name: Bob
Age: 20
Goals: 
    - Goal 1, complete in X days
    - Goal 2, complete in Y days
```

and so on.. I don't want to statically add 3 labels (Name, Age, Goals) and their respective JTextAreas (Bob, 20, Goal 1/Goal 2), because the structure of Person will likely change in the future.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: cant you just store all your Person Information in a single `JTextArea`?

Comment: The user should be able to update and change the Person information (and then save it back to the array), so I don't think one big JTA would be plausible.

Comment: i think what you are looking for is [Reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) - doesnt have any experience with it so i cant help you out :/

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you can get what you want by creating anonymous instances of `JLabel` and `JTextArea` and placing them into an array list. I don't know the specifics of your environment, but hopefully, you can follow the idea:

```
ArrayList<JLabel> nameLabelList = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
ArrayList<JLabel> ageLabelList = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
ArrayList<Goal> goalList = new ArrayList<Goal>();

// Event handler method

public void personSelected(person)
{
    nameLabelList.add(person.name);
    ageLabelList.add(person.age);
    // This assumes each person has a single goal. You can adapt the code
    // for multiple goals easily
    goalLabelList.add(person.goal);
}
```

Then, after the lists are created, all you have to do is loop through these array lists and spit them out into your UI:

```
for(int counter = 0; counter < nameLabelList.size; counter++)
{
   myContainer.add(nameLabelList.get(counter));
   myContainer.add(ageLabelList.get(counter));
   myContainer.add(new JLabel(goalList.get(counter).toString()));
}
```

After adding the contents of the array lists, make sure that they show up in the UI:

```
   myContainer.revalidate();
   myContainter.repaint();
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add new Panels to your Main Panel. So your Main Panel should provide a scrollable inner Panel to which you add new lines. If you have ever worked with HTML and Tables you will understand what I am talking about.
Once you got this attribute-show-panel (inner Panel), you can load as many attributes into it with a for loop as you want. 
The code would technically be like for each goal in goalArray -> add new linePanel to attribute-show-panel.
whereas a linePanel yould store a label, abutton, etc and many line Panels would list vertically